# Why route throws 401 when Cypress test clicks on link but it is OK when tested manually?

Tags: cypress, http-status-code-401

I'm aware this sounds like a back-end issue at first but I suspect Cypress causing this route to throw 401 for some reason.
When I test logout route manually it gives me 200 status code back and UI changes accordingly.
However when Cypress tests the logout route back-end returns 401 and rest of the test fail as well because other tests depend on logout route returning 200.

[image]

Backend isn't giving me any error outputs besides status code 401 on that route.
I'm using token authentication. Tokens are stored in browser's local storage but that
should have no effect on how Cypress tests routes.

If you need any info ask away.

Any suggestions ?